# Slave protection from master in I2C

Tags: i2c

I am trying to answer this question:

> How can an I2C slave protect itself from being overwhelmed by an I2C master?

I think the answer is this:

---

As what I know is for each transmitted bit, the master device pulses the clock. This speed must be followed by the slave. Because even slaves need to rest now and then, a slave device can hold down the clock line until it is ready to communicate again. This method is known as clock stretching, and it ensures that a slave device may prevent itself from being addressed too rapidly.

---

Is that correct?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. You seem to have answered your own question here, so I don't know what you're looking for. Please be aware that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Take the tour if you have any confusion. Again, welcome.

Comment: There's nothing the slave can do if the frequency is too high or if it gets addressed too frequently. Clockstretching only delays the ACK after a transmitted byte.

Comment: I trying to ask for a check with my answer because I am not too sure whether this answer is acceptable, I forgot my account password and created a new one. And yea thanks for your welcome.

Comment: @SimSon That is not true, clock stretching is not limited to bytes or ACK bits.

Comment: What would like the outcome to be (in terms of what useful function will protection achieve that isn't accomplished by the master respecting the slave's timing requirements). In other words, it's the master that holds all the cards and it has to obey certain timing relationships if it expects to be "master" of something that is useful to it.

Comment: Re, "How can an I2C slave protect itself..." Why would it _need_ to protect itself? Connecting arbitrary, 3rd-party peripherals to a host is not a design goal of \$\text{I}^2\text{C}\$. All of the the devices on the bus should have been chosen and approved by the same design team, and it's those designers who bear the responsibility to ensure that the devices will interoperate with each other to meet the needs of the application.

Comment: @Justme, It depends which speed mode you specify the device to work at. For standard and fast modes, stretching individual bits is allowed, for Hs mode only stretching the ACK bit is allowed.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, What do you mean "I2C is plug and play?" Are you talking about SMBus and, about how PCI daughter cards can connect to a motherboard SMBus? That's a subject about which I don't have a lot of knowledge. But, I did once write code for an embedded system that used SMBus. I know that the SMBus spec leaves a lot less room for creative interpretation than I2C allows. E.g., SMBus must use specific voltages, a narrow range of clock frequencies,  strict limits on clock stretching... I'd guess an SMBus slave could _mostly_ "protect" itself just by obeying the spec.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I2C is not plug and play. What do you mean by saying it is? Also to OP the clock stretching is not the only way of slave chip saying it is not ready, there are other ways as well, just look up how I2C EEPROMs work.

Answer (score -2):

This should be taken into account during the design phase. Clock stretching works but not every I2C devices supports that. Part of this can be controlled by the master by not sending more data then the slave can adsorb. Slowing the I2C clock would help and may solve the problem. I2C is not intended as a bus between modules but to be used on a PCB to connect different peripheral devices. There is a design process called DFEMA (Design  Failure Mode Effect Analysis). DFMEA is a systematic group of activities used to recognize and evaluate potential systems, products or process failures. DFMEA identifies the effects and outcomes of these failures or actions.